# How can I stop drivers for Nvidia GeForce GT 330M causing issues in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, graphic-drivers, drivers, nvidia

After installation of Nvidia proprietary drivers window control buttons doesn't work (elementary OS apps window buttons work but rest [firefox, playonlinux] doesn't). In addition switching windows doesn't work always and system occasionally freezes.

I have Nvidia GeForce GT 330M. Installed driver via

`sudo apt install nvidia-current`

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First remove what you've done with `sudo apt remove nvidia-current`  and reboot.
Then open Appcenter, go to the Installed tab and install one Nvidia driver from the available ones. Then reboot and update your question with any issue that you might have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the opensource drivers are still being loaded. I have noticed a bit more stability when I set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau rhgb"`
in `/etc/default/grub`. Then run

```
$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and reboot.

Comment: Problem still occurs.. :/

Comment: sorry to hear that.  I still have problems with graphics when coming out of suspend. It appears that elementary and nvidia dedicated graphics aren't all that compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I used driver directly from nvidia Homepage (after purging all nvidia* packages including nuovo). Works like a charm. Only backlight worked with nvidiabl as i discribed in an other article. What says nvidia-settings gui program? Is your system up to date? I hope it is nota specific GT 330m issue. I use geforce 9400m.